# Is there a way to replace a maven dependency formerly hosted by pyx4me.com?

Tags: java, maven

i am trying to build a large java codebase that uses maven as it's build tool.
However, building (`mvn clean install -DskipTests`) always results in the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.pyx4j:maven-junction-plugin:1.0.3:unlink (unlink) on project flink-dist_2.10:  Execution unlink of goal com.pyx4j:maven-junction-plugin:1.0.3:unlink failed: Plugin com.pyx4j:maven-junction-plugin:1.0.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for com.pyx4j:maven-junction-plugin:jar:1.0.3 (): Failed to read artifact descriptor for sysinternals:junction:exe:1.04: Could not transfer artifact sysinternals:junction:pom:1.04 from/to pyx4me-web (http://www.pyx4me.com/maven2): Connection to http://www.pyx4me.com refused: Connection refused (Connection refused) -> [Help 1]
```

I don't really know anything about maven, so i'm a litte lost on what to do.

I've tried to manually install the maven-junction-plugin in the local .m2 directory. However, that was before i understood that it's not the .jar that is missing, but some dependency of that jar.

I would be really grateful for any hints or insight from someone that knows anything about maven.

Comment: The problem is: `Connection refused..`..

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is the following: even though, the maven-junction-plugin artifact, version 1.0.3 is available in maven central repository, it tries to download a dependency called **sysinternals:junction:exe:1.04** from (http://www.pyx4me.com/maven2) but the connection times out (You can also try to ping pyx4me.com and you will find out it is not responsive).

The maven-junction-plugin was in use by the Apache Flink before 1.2 Release.
The current stable versions of Apache Flink do not use it anymore. In fact the project seems abandonned and not supported anymore.

Please see the following [maven's central Jira ticket](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-1365) asking for a removal of it from maven central.

So it looks like there is no simple way to do what you are trying to do.
But you might be able to hack a bit around it.

First it looks like systinternal:junction:1.04 is not available anywhere, but the 1.07 version is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/junction) (it is possible that it won't be compatible with maven-junction-plugin 1.04, so you need to test it enough to make sure it is)

The zip contains the .exe in two flavors (a 32 and a 64 bits versions). Use the version that suits your need and install it in your local repository.

The general approach to install an artifact in your local repository would be the one described [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html), but since we are dealing with an .exe file you would rather use the procedure described [here](https://rolfje.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/non-java-binary-dependencies-in-maven/)

Now let's assume that you have successfully installed the systinernal:junction:1.07 in your local repository with the following artifact properties:

- groupId: your-group-id
- artifactId: junction
- version: 1.07
- type: exe

You can use the [jar installation in local repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) approach to install the plugin's jar along with a customized version of the pom where you point to your local version of the systinternal:junction dependency instead of the original version. You can find both files [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.pyx4j/maven-junction-plugin/1.0.3).

The dependencies section of your customized pom will then look like:

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>your-group-id</groupId>
      <artifactId>junction</artifactId>
      <version>1.07</version>
      <type>exe</type>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
   </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

you can remove the old **repositories** section as the remote repository is not working anyway.

In my opinion, it is too much of a hacking (and you will probably have hard time convincing your colleagues to bring something like this in production). So I suggest to try to find an equivalent of the functionalities your are using this plugin for.